# terminal git status helper listed in .bashrc and .bash_profile not loading unless you source .bash_profile

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, terminal, git

I have the following neat helper, that I found online, that displays my current git branch at all times if I am in a git repo:

```
parse_git_branch() {
     git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}
export PS1="\u@\h \[\e[32m\]\w \[\e[91m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\e[00m\]$ "
```

I have it in my `.bashrc`:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

parse_git_branch() {
     git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}
export PS1="\u@\h \[\e[32m\]\w \[\e[91m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\e[00m\]$ "

source ~/.bash_profile
...
```

for some reason I put it in my `.bash_profile` too

```
parse_git_branch() {
     git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}
export PS1="\u@\h \[\e[32m\]\w \[\e[91m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\e[00m\]$ "
```

If I run `source ~/.bash_profile'` it works, and shows the git branch. However, if I add a new terminal by doing the ctrl+shift+t that adds a new terminal to the right it doesn't show up. if I clear out of the ubuntu terminal and reopen it and cd into a git repo it also doesn't show up.

Comment: You might find a clue in [Zsh/Bash startup files loading order (.bashrc, .zshrc etc.) | The Lumber Room](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/)

Comment: (1) When it doesn't work, what if you `exec bash`? (2) What terminal emulator are we talking about? (3) The terminal emulator is probably configured to run a command. Is the command `/bin/bash`? or more complicated like `/bin/bash --norc`?

Comment: `exec bash` takes away the desired git branch display if it was already showing

Comment: i am using the default terminal for ubuntu 22. how do  I find what command it runs

Comment: Reading which files load in what order helped as it wasn't an issue of having the code in the wrong file

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there are more settings for the `PS1` variable that determines your terminal display. About halfway down the `.bashrc` file:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\>
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

If I move my git branch display to the bottom of `.bashrc` it now works upon opening any new terminal